# Rotating VML groups with RaphaelJS (doesn't appear to be working)

Tags: javascript, vector, raphael, vml

I'm trying to build a crossbrowser vector application, and to do so am using VML instead of SVG for IE7 and IE8.

I'm trying to figure out how to rotate the VML group element, and has it working in pure VML but as soon as I incorporate RaphaelJS it breaks.

Is there a way to rotate VML groups in RaphaelJS?

Here is a zip file with both the working VML only solution, and the broken Raphael solution:
http://voostmedia.com/vml_testing.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation is broken in Raphael2.0/2.0.1
I switched back to 1.5.2 until it is fixed

Comment: Tried both versions :( - No difference, I think that it has something to do with group elements in VML.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Raphael.Freetransform](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform). It handles rotation of sets and it works in older versions of IE. You can try the demo here:

http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/